# System.InvalidOperationException: 'A method was called at an unexpected time when calling LaunchUriAsync inside ToastNotification UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to open the browser with a specific URL using the method `LaunchUriAsync` when the user clicks a Toast notification.

The problem is that the application throws `System.InvalidOperationException: 'A method was called at an unexpected time`.

This only happens inside the `Activated` event handler of the `ToastNotification`.

If I execute this method outside the `Activated` event handler of the `ToastNotification` everything works fine.

Here is the code:

```cs
private async void OnActivatedEventHandler<TSender, TResult>(TSender sender, TResult args)
{
  Uri uri = new Uri("...");
  bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
}
```

Can someone explain me why this happens ?

It's welcome any other approach to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message said that the method is called at an unexpected time. From the document of [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-19041), the remarks mentions that-'Unless you are calling this API from a Windows desktop application, **this API must be called from within an ASTA thread (also known as the UI thread).**' You need to call this method in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to resolve it by calling `LaunchUriAsync` inside the `OnActivated` method of the `App` page and using action buttons on the Toast.